# How to set default value in the combobox in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am creating an application where I need a tkinter combox. There I want the combo box to have a default value from the starting of the application. I have tried `current()` method but it is not working.

Here is my code snipped

```
n= tk.StringVar()
youtubechoicesLabel = ttk.Combobox(root, font=font, justify='center', textvariable=n)
youtubechoicesLabel['values'] = ("----Download Type----",
                                    "Mp4  720p",
                                    "Mp4  144p",
                                    "Video  3gp",
                                    "Audio  Mp3")

youtubechoicesLabel.current(0)
youtubechoicesLabel["background"] = '#ff0000'
youtubechoicesLabel["foreground"] = '#ffffff'
youtubechoicesLabel.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `current()` is correct and it is working — you just can't see the current selection due to the use the white `foreground` color you specified.

```
n = tk.StringVar()
youtubechoicesLabel = ttk.Combobox(root, font=font, justify='center', textvariable=n)
youtubechoicesLabel['values'] = ("----Download Type----",
                                    "Mp4  720p",
                                    "Mp4  144p",
                                    "Video  3gp",
                                    "Audio  Mp3")

youtubechoicesLabel.current(0)
youtubechoicesLabel["background"] = '#ff0000'
#youtubechoicesLabel["foreground"] = '#ffffff'  # <----- DISABLED
youtubechoicesLabel.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the value of n.

```
n.set('default value')
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily setting the default value of `n`, it's just setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable `foreground` color and **bind an event** to your combobox. I had the same issue and the above solutions didn't work for me. I fixed it by binding an event to it.

```
n = tk.StringVar()
youtubechoicesLabel = ttk.Combobox(window, justify='center', textvariable=n)
youtubechoicesLabel['values'] = ("----Download Type----",
                                    "Mp4  720p",
                                    "Mp4  144p",
                                    "Video  3gp",
                                    "Audio  Mp3")

youtubechoicesLabel["background"] = '#ff0000'
#youtubechoicesLabel["foreground"] = '#ffffff' #disable it as martineau said
youtubechoicesLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=20)
youtubechoicesLabel.current(0)

#bind an event to your youtubechoicesLabel
def ComboboxEvent(event):
    print("some event")

youtubechoicesLabel.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", ComboboxEvent)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The event is triggered when you select the combobox but I want to set the default on combobox creation